# Hexgit number?

Tags: math, hex, nomenclature

if digit is the name for a number on base 10, what would be the name for a number on base 16? Hexgit?

Comment: What does this have to do with etiquette? Characters won't be offended if we call them by the wrong names.

Comment: What do you suggest? a ne tag maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Digit*. Simply a hexadecimal one.

Are you looking for an analogue to *bit* for *binary digit*? *Hexgit* wouldn't be my choice; it doesn't really roll off the tongue. As for the unit of storage, a hex digit represents a *nibble*'s worth (or *nybble*).

Comment: hahahahaha....I just made up Hexgit....

Comment: "Hexit" would be easier to say, but I don't see anyone using that word in this context. Perhaps there simply isn't demand for a separate word.

Comment: I've used hexit for a long time, as has everyone else i know in the field

Answer (score 8):

It's a "nibble" (i.e., half a byte).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble

Comment: ha! I haven't heard of nibbles in years.

Comment: Also we'd accept nybble.

Comment: That page also says that nibble corresponds to hexadecimal digit: hexit.

Answer (score 2):

[define: digit](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+digit)

One of the elements that collectively form a system of numeration.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'digit' can be used in any number system. The only exceptions are 'bit' which is really just short for 'binary digit' and 'trit' which is short for 'ternary digit'. (You can still call bits and trits 'digits', however.)

Comment: "trit" and not "tit"?  The "r" is not even beside the "t"!  :)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a consensus, I don't think, but see [Units of information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information) for some options.

Personally, I'd just say "hex digit".

Answer (score 1):

Still "digit", as long as you have 16 fingers  ;-)

Comment: +1 for making me laugh...jajajaj

Answer (score 1):

"Hexdigit" and "hex digit" are both in wide use in textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

"Hexgit" would be a bad choice since "hex" formally suggests base six rather than 16.

"Hexdecit" would retain the 6+10 representation, but I would stick with "digit".